# How to properly, with the most possible freedom, add a formula into a plot?

Tags: plotting, formatting, latex, plot-themes

I would like to know the best way(s) to add a formula into a plot, with the most possible freedom ever. And I mean: possibility of writing the formula the dimension of which can be modified, put into whatever part of the plot I want, written in any possible colour and so on.

I know I'm pretty demanding..
This is what I was able to do so far:

```
Plot[d[10, 1, 1, 2, t, 0], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Times", Black, Bold}, 
PlotStyle -> {{Darker[Blue], DotDashed, Thickness[0.004]}, {Red, 
Thickness[0.004]}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}, AxesStyle -> Bold, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {t [sec], \[ScriptCapitalD][t]}, 
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}, AxesStyle -> Bold, 
FrameStyle -> {{Directive[FontColor -> Darker[Red]], 
Automatic}, {Directive[FontColor -> Darker[Red]], Automatic}}, 
Epilog -> 
Inset[HoldForm@
TraditionalForm[
 Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalD], 
   0] \[Theta][
    t - Subscript[t, 0]]/(1 + 
     Log[1 + \[Alpha] t] (c + Sin[\[Beta] t])), {0.3, 0.9}]]]
```

The last part doesn't work, indeed the formula is always at the center of the plot, small written..

Any help?

Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: Please do not add unrelated tags. What is the relationship to LaTeX? If none, remove the tag.

Answer (score 1):

What about adding Style between Inset and HoldForm for the text style, and adding Scaled before closing the Inset parenthesis for the position in the plot:

```
Plot[d[10, 1, 1, 2, t, 0], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Times", Black, Bold}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Darker[Blue], DotDashed, Thickness[0.004]}, {Red, 
    Thickness[0.004]}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}, AxesStyle -> Bold, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {t[sec], \[ScriptCapitalD][t]}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}, AxesStyle -> Bold, 
 FrameStyle -> {{Directive[FontColor -> Darker[Red]], 
    Automatic}, {Directive[FontColor -> Darker[Red]], Automatic}}, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[
   Style[
    HoldForm@
     TraditionalForm[
      Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalD], 
        0] \[Theta][
         t - Subscript[t, 0]]/(1 + 
          Log[1 + \[Alpha] t] (c + Sin[\[Beta] t])), {0.3,0.9}], 
     {Red, 20}], 
    Scaled[{0.4, 0.2}]
   ]
 ]
```

In my example the formula is Red, dimension 20px, and placed at the bottom-left of the plot.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, which doesn't really answer to the question but it holds a bit. Write it as a PlotLabel question:

```
PlotLabel->Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalD], 
0] \[Theta][
t - Subscript[t, 0]]/(1 + Log[1 + \[Alpha] t] (c + Sin[\[Beta] t]))
```